# How can I add a click event to li element listview in Phonegap JQM?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm having problems adding a click event to a dynamically populated listview using JQM and Phonegap (A static list works correctly). The listview populates and applies css correctly but when I try to add a click event using the `$("#test li".on("click")` the id is not selected and no code executes. Any ideas?

**JS :**

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

   function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
   }

   function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("external_sd/Music", {
            create: false,
            exclusive: false
        }, getDirSuccess, fail);
    }

    function getDirSuccess(dirEntry) {
        // Get a directory reader
        var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
        // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
        directoryReader.readEntries(readerSuccess, fail);
    }

    function readerSuccess(entries) {
        for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            $("#test").append("<li>" + entries[i].name + "</li>");
            $("#test").listview("refresh");
        }
    }

    $("#test ul li").on("click", function (event) {
        alert($(this).text());
    }); //this code doesn't execute.

    function fail(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
        alert("some error occured");
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div data-role="page" id="albumspage">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>MyApp</h1>      

    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">    
       <ul id="test" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true">                 
       </ul>   
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>footer</h1>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

 </div><!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The correct way

Some mistakes in your code :

- You must use the `pageinit` event of `albumspage` to render the listview, not using the `deviceReady` event.
- You must use `refresh` ONLY once, after everything is done appending.
- You are appending your `li` inside `$("#test")`. But when you're selecting the element for click event, you are using `$("#test ul li")`. That can mean two things : either the way `append`ing is done is wrong or your selector for `click` function is wrong. From the HTML its clear that you have the wrong selector in `click`.

So finally your code must look like this :

```
function readerSuccess(entries) {
    var li = "";
    for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        li += "<li>" + entries[i].name + "</li>";
    }
    $("#test").append(li).promise().done(function () {
        //refresh list here 
        $(this).listview("refresh");
        //then add click event using delegation
        $(this).on("click", "li", function () {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    });
}

$(document).on("pageinit", "#albumspage", function () {
    //get entries from DB
    readerSuccess(entries);
});
```

### Alternative

But if still want to use `onDeviceReady` event, then you might want to change your `click` event to this :

```
$(document).on("click", "#test li" ,function (event) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

This binding to `document` will ensure that the click will always fire.

Comment: thanks! I managed to get it working using the alternative method. The first response doesn't work for me, but still trying to get my headaround how these pageinit events work as it looks the better solution in the long run. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$("#test").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
 var control = $(this);
}
```